# Instagram API using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, instagram, instagram-api

I am currently using Instagram API in the sandbox mode using Python's `python-instagram` library. Now, I have an application and its associated client id, client secret and access token, and one connected sandbox user.

Earlier today, I was experimenting with the `users/search` endpoint. First, I directly used their endpoint URL to send a request:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=XXXX&access_token=<my_access_token>
```

where `XXXX` is the connected sandbox user of my Instagram application. This is the generated response:

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"data":[{"username":"XXXX","bio":"Twitter: @XXXX","website":"","profile_picture":"https:a.jpg","full_name":"XXXX XXXX","id":"22222222"}]}
```

Now, I tried using the `python-instagram` library to send request to the same endpoint as follows:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
access_token = <my_access_token>

api = InstagramAPI(client_secret='aaaa', access_token = access_token[0])
usr = api.user_search('XXXX')

print usr
```

However, this is the response I get in this case:

```
[User: XXXX]
```

Why is it that I get different responses when I try to call the same endpoint using the direct URL and the Python library?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What `python-instagram` is doing is that it will take the raw JSON response you get when you issue an HTTP request, and map it to python objects.

When you issue a `print usr`, you are printing a `User` object that's in a list, so you see a string which is `[User: XXXX]`.

You can find the model they use for the User object [here](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/blob/master/instagram/models.py#L193). It actually directly maps the fields from the Json to get attributes.

Try the following code to retrieve a username and id:

```
my_usr = usr[0]
print 'User id is', my_usr.id, 'and name is ', my_usr.username
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for this.

Comment: No problem. I like to use IPython to work with object-based libraries (and API libraries do that quite a lot). IPython allows for a lot of useful stuff, including automatic completion. For example you could have done `my_usr.` and pressed the tab key to know immediatly what the fields are. You could also use `dict(my_usr)` but it is not as pretty.

Comment: Indeed using the interactive python autocompletion gives you a huge insight of the current objects/methdos avail everytime.